# ReadProcessMemory reads Memory backwards?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When using ReadProcessMemory to read memory of an executable file, the first two bytes that I get are reversed. The code is:

```
SIZE_T dataRead;
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) malloc(1);
ReadProcessMemory(process, (LPVOID)addr, dosHeader, 2, &dataRead);
printf("%x\n", dosHeader->e_magic);
```

The above outputs 5A4D instead of 4D5A. Why would that be? Could it endianess?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it could be endianness. Also it could be that you're trying to use a buffer that is 1 byte big to read 2 bytes. It should be `(PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) malloc(sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is due to endianness.  The first byte in the file is `0x4d`, the second byte is `0x5a`.  When you print these using `%x`, they are interpreted as being a little endian number, so the bytes are swapped when they are printed.  Consider, as a self-contained example, the following program:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    assert(sizeof(unsigned) == 4);

    char bytes[4] = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78 };
    std::printf("%x\n", *reinterpret_cast<unsigned const*>(bytes));
}
```

On a system with a little-endian byte ordering, the output will be `78563412`.  (This example program ignores potential alignment issues; since you are using Visual C++, there will be no problems.)

Note also that you are overrunning your one byte allocation (you `malloc(1)` but read two bytes).

Comment: Actually, i get the same result when allocating two bytes. Could you explain how can it be endianess? I thought Intel follows little endian so why is it that when I reading memory, i get the result back in a different endian (presumably big endian)? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your explanation is still not clear to me. When I run the code through the debugger, the value of the first 2 bytes is 23117 which in hex is 5A4D. So even in memory, the order of the bytes are flipped? I presume that means the printf is not flipping the bytes...?

Comment: The debugger is also interpreting the bytes as a short integer (16-bit integer).  When you print a little-endian integer, the bytes appear reversed.  If you watch `*reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&dosHeader->e_magic)` in the debugger, you will see that the first byte does indeed contain `0x4d`.